# HTML/CSS : scrolling rectangle not working

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website and want to add a top bar and footer with some elements on it.
I also would create a rectangle surface where I can write my text.

This is the actual result I got with the code below (part):

[image: "result 1"]

```css
div.custom-bg {
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  ;
  background-image: url("../img/bg32.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

div.alpha-layer {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  height: 500%;
  width: 86%
}

div.top-bar {
  background-color: rgb(32, 42, 52);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
}

div.footer {
  background-color: rgb(32, 42, 52);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-bg">
  <div class="top-bar"></div>
  <div class="alpha-layer">
    <p> " Lorem ipsum... ( cut ) Curabitur eu amet."</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

But You can see on the picture that there is no scrolling bar to read the full text!
Before, there was a scrolling bar but not anymore...

I would be able to add stuff and the top bar and the footer bar.
What did I do wrong ?

This is what I trying to achieve (this is a photoshopped image):

[image]

Comment: Works with the code you provided. Look for an `overflow: hidden` rule. Should be `auto` or `scroll`

Comment: Oh ? this is soo strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.custom-bg {
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

div.alpha-layer {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  height: 500%;
  width: 86%
}

div.top-bar {
  background-color: rgb(32, 42, 52);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
}

div.footer {
  background-color: rgb(32, 42, 52);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
}

div.alpha-layer p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-bg">
  <div class="top-bar"></div>
  <div class="alpha-layer">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sollicitudin varius feugiat. Curabitur facilisis purus purus, et posuere ex auctor a. Maecenas ut ante sit amet tortor suscipit bibendum non at lacus. Pellentesque ut nisi lectus. Fusce
      feugiat lacus in odio suscipit condimentum. Cras nec cursus dui. Pellentesque lectus mi, dictum sed placerat non, consectetur malesuada enim. Fusce faucibus ipsum risus, ut malesuada odio feugiat sed. Cras a tellus sit amet ligula posuere tempor
      eu eget nunc. Proin tempor tortor elementum, sagittis eros vitae, blandit neque. Vivamus ut est urna. Ut orci nisi, eleifend ac sapien in, tempor hendrerit urna. Curabitur molestie, nunc a pretium tincidunt, eros nibh porttitor enim, non tincidunt
      risus nulla et libero. Duis eu tincidunt tellus. Vestibulum magna velit, dapibus at lectus non, mollis pretium augue. Sed dignissim scelerisque nisi eu porta. Maecenas vestibulum et enim at porta. Phasellus varius placerat dui ac ultricies. Etiam
      in ex vel massa fermentum mollis vel eu odio. In pharetra lectus in tellus finibus venenatis. Nunc pretium consequat mattis. Nulla ornare metus et vulputate ultricies. Phasellus ac ante accumsan, lacinia velit et, auctor mauris. Etiam vitae convallis
      risus. Proin libero diam, posuere vel eros sed, tempus aliquet ligula. Praesent non tellus porttitor, eleifend erat vel, congue dolor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam vel imperdiet
      dolor. Donec molestie vestibulum mi, id dapibus urna cursus ac. Duis dignissim congue fringilla. Vestibulum nec venenatis eros, et ultrices nisl. Etiam eu dui lectus. Pellentesque lacinia volutpat sem sit amet hendrerit. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus
      vitae scelerisque velit, nec varius leo. Proin a mi convallis odio eleifend dignissim non quis sem. Vestibulum et nulla congue, porta nisl quis, molestie dui. Vivamus pellentesque maximus nisl a euismod. Maecenas elit neque, imperdiet vitae augue
      vitae, sagittis vestibulum dui. Nam non pulvinar enim. Nunc hendrerit magna id felis lobortis finibus. Quisque vel ante nunc. Curabitur eget urna ut elit interdum convallis. Ut porta justo est. Donec egestas enim vitae leo egestas, sed egestas dui
      lobortis. Fusce nec facilisis justo. Nulla sodales sem eget purus tincidunt, non fermentum justo egestas. Pellentesque magna sem, molestie eget feugiat ac, hendrerit vel sem. Integer eget justo non ipsum suscipit euismod. Donec eu leo in diam laoreet
      gravida eu eget arcu. Proin vehicula elementum magna, non fringilla lectus sagittis a. Aenean id hendrerit nunc. Praesent urna leo, sagittis maximus mollis bibendum, dignissim in sem. Etiam ut mattis lorem. Etiam fermentum lacus nec mollis feugiat.
      Sed pellentesque nisl enim, in hendrerit augue facilisis ac. Maecenas elit neque, imperdiet vitae augue vitae, sagittis vestibulum dui. Nam non pulvinar enim. Nunc hendrerit magna id felis lobortis finibus. Quisque vel ante nunc. Curabitur eget
      urna ut elit interdum convallis. Ut porta justo est. Donec egestas enim vitae leo egestas, sed egestas dui lobortis. Fusce nec facilisis justo. Nulla sodales sem eget purus tincidunt, non fermentum justo egestas. Pellentesque magna sem, molestie
      eget feugiat ac, hendrerit vel sem. Integer eget justo non ipsum suscipit euismod. Donec eu leo in diam laoreet gravida eu eget arcu. Proin vehicula elementum magna, non fringilla lectus sagittis a. Aenean id hendrerit nunc. Praesent urna leo, sagittis
      maximus mollis bibendum, dignissim in sem. Etiam ut mattis lorem. Etiam fermentum lacus nec mollis feugiat. Sed pellentesque nisl enim, in hendrerit augue facilisis ac."</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```